# EJB Timers hang when checking for status

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am using EJB Timers in my application, but the application hangs whenever I check for timer status.

Scenario to replicate this is below:

1) Start the timer.

2) In timeout method, call another class method and sleep there for 30 minutes.

3) Before the 30 minutes expire, check for the timer status by calling below method.

```
    public String getTimerStatus() {
    String returnStatus = "Stopped";
    for (Object obj : timerService.getTimers()) {
        Timer t = (Timer) obj;
        try {
            String scheduled = (String) t.getInfo();
            if (scheduled.equals(TIMER_NAME)) {
                returnStatus = "Running";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return returnStatus;
}
```

**4) Application hangs when t.getInfo() method is called, as shown above.**

Please let me know any resolution for this issue.

Comment: Can you show some more code? My idea is that you are managing threads that should be managed by the container. This may cause the troubles you are experiencing

Answer (score 0):

My idea is that t.getInfo() is synchronized or tries to get a lock in another way. Could you provide the code for the timeout method and for the other class method it calls? Do you use synchronization?